# Send Array of strings from red5 (Java) to Flash (ActionScript 3)?

Tags: java, arrays, actionscript-3, flash, red5

i want to send an array of strings from my red5 server to my flash aplication. But i'm doing something wrong. this is my code.

Red5 server:

```
public String[] listUsers(){

String users[]={"Jordi","Anne","Charly"};

return u;

}
```

ActionScript 3:

```
var result:Responder = new Responder(onResult,onFail);
connection.call("listUsers", result);

function onResult(result:Object):void
{
    var users:Array=new Array ();
    users=result.valueOf();

}
```

and the error (in spanish):

TypeError: Error #1034: Error de conversión forzada: no se puede convertir 5 en Array.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: users=result.split(",");

Comment: In what form do you send it to flash?

Comment: are you using simple GET/POST requests or some frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

```
 flash.external.ExternalInterface.call(function_name:String[, arg1, ...]):Object;

 var result:Responder = new Responder(onResult,onFail);

 flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("listUsers", result);

 function onResult(result:Object):void
 {
     var users:Array=new Array ();
     users=result.valueOf();

 }
```

Note that your syntax reflects more a FMS server call rather then Javascript I am not sure that i am understanding your question. If it is on the server you will likely want the rpc service
like RemoteObject
     
for FMS and Wowza use a netConnection and nc.call("myFunctionNameInQuotes","param1",param2 , etc);